# React Formik - app performs unwanted request (submit) after pressing Enter key in the input field

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

When I write something in the "name" field and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, app performs a request, address bar in the web browser changes to `http://localhost:3000/?name=something`. But when I just add another input field to the form, app behaviour changes: it doesn't perform request in such case. I would like to ask:

  1. Why app behaviour is dependent on the number of input fields?

  2. How can I force app to not perform submit (request) when there is
      only one field in the form, to act like there would be many fields?

```
import {Formik} from 'formik';

function App() {

    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <Formik>
                {props => (
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" name="name"/>
                        {/*If I uncomment the line below, the app will not perform request after pressing Enter*/}
                        {/*<input type="text" name="surname"/>*/}
                    </form>
                )}
            </Formik>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your validation is just stoping it when you have two fields.  HTML form should submit by default when you hit enter. You have an html form.

If you can, I would just remove the html form element and manually control the submit.

```
<Formik
   initialValues={{ name: 'test' }}
   onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
       actions.setSubmitting(false);
     }, 1000);
   }}
 >
   {props => (
     <>
       <input
         type="text"
         onChange={props.handleChange}
         onBlur={props.handleBlur}
         value={props.values.name}
         name="name"
       />
       {props.errors.name && <div id="feedback">{props.errors.name}</div>}
       <button onClick={props.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
     </>
   )}
 </Formik>
```

Or just use the formik "Form" component and create a custom event handler for the enter key press.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a couple of things..

You need to have a [validationSchema](https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation).

You can do this with yup, or write your own.

Inside the Formik tag, you should then add the following fields

```
<Formik
initialValues={{ name: "", surname: "" }}
onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
validationSchema={validationSchema}>
```

Comment: I have replaced line: `<Formik>` with `<Formik initialValues={{ name: "", surname: "" }} onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)} validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({name: Yup.string().min(0, 'Too Short!'),})} >` It does not help. Please remember that there would be only one input field named `name`, there would not be input field `surname`. Could you tell me what should I change to make it work?

Comment: In that case, remove the surname field from initialValues. Your validationSchema looks ok.